# Unittest mock return_value doesn't work properly

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

Can anybody please explain me why 1st example is working and 2nd one returns an error?
Apparently I don't quite understand how return_value works.
Thank you beforehand!

1st example:

```
#function
def return_request_get(url):
    return requests.get(url)

#test
    def test_request(self):
        with patch('requests.get', return_value='Hello World!') as mr:
            self.assertEqual(return_request_get('https://www.django-rest-framework.org/'), 'Hello World!')

#returns OK
```

2nd example

```
#function
def return_request_status_code(url):
    return requests.get(url).status_code

#test
    def test_request_status_code(self):
        requests.get = Mock()
        requests.get.status_code.return_value = 200
        self.assertEqual(return_request_status_code('notrealurl'), 200)


#returns 
200 != <Mock name='mock().status_code' id='139997783798160'>

Expected :<Mock name='mock().status_code' id='139997783798160'>
Actual   :200
```

BUT!

If I rewrite 2nd test this way it works perfectly:

```
def test_request_status_code(self):
    with patch('requests.get') as mock_request:
        mock_request.return_value.status_code = 200
        self.assertEqual(return_request_status_code('notrealurl'), 200)
```

Comment: `return_value` is used for the result of a callable, e.g. a function or a class instantiation - for a simple attribute it does not make sense, you can just set that.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen sorry I am completely new at this. Can you please be a little bit more specific? How exactly can I set it?

Comment: Well, you already did it in your rewrite. if you set `mock_request.return_value`, you basically set the value of `mock_request()`, e.g. an instance of the mocked class. `status_code` is an attribute, and `status_code.return_value` would be the result of `status_code()` - which makes no sense, as it is not a callable.